Reading last line from a log file within a loop
I'm trying hard to write a script function that reads the last line of a log file while that file is being updated, to use it in arguments.
My idea is to stop the loop when a file is created by another function of the same script. That seems to work. However, after spending hours, I have not been able to actually get the data from the log file.
Got these two versions now;
while true; do
    if [[ -f "CheckFile" ]]; then
        break
    else
        Variable=$(tail -n 1 "${LogFile}" | grep -E "(Installing.*\ of \.*)")
        echo "${Variable}"
    fi
done
rm -f "CheckFile"

while true; do
    if [[ -f "CheckFile" ]]; then
        break
    else
        while read line; do
            if [[ -n $line ]]; then
                echo "test $line"
            else
                continue
            fi
        done < <(tail -n 1 "${LogFile}" | grep -E "(Installing.*\ of \.*)")
    fi
done
rm -f "CheckFile"

I expected both versions will give an updated value as long as the while loop runs. Also tried with tail -f, but that seems to never end.

Use tail -f in the < <(...) approach. And mind your buffering. The tail -n 1 approach without -f has serious race conditions: if multiple lines are written at a time you risk seeing only the last one in the batch, plus starting /usr/bin/tail over and over and over is massively inefficient. (The same is true for starting grep over and over and over, for that matter -- if you're doing this right you'll start tail and grep only once per invocation of your script)

Separately, tag bash or zsh, but never both in the same question. (The tag should match the shebang: If you start your script with #!/usr/bin/env bash, tag bash; if you start it with #!/usr/bin/env zsh, tag zsh; if you start it with #!/bin/sh, tag sh, not bash or zsh)

(about "mind your buffering" -- if you don't configure grep to flush and you're using properly long-lived instances, it'll wait until it has 32kb of content that passed the filter ready to write, so there'll be a long delay before the while read can read things that grep matched; if you have GNU grep, --line-buffered will turn that off; if you don't have a guarantee of GNU tools, personally, I'd do the filtering on the bash side -- [[ $line = *Installing*" of "* ]] || continue is pretty straightforward).

If the loop does not terminate, it simply means that the file named CheckFile is never created in your working directory. You can refer this easily by putting, just for debugging, a ls CheckFile inside the loop. BTW, the loop can be written simpler as while [[ ! -f CheckFile ]].
